# How can i unify classes that have same purpose but different input and output to one interface

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I need to unify few classes that have same purposes but and use same method but with different parameters and results.

It probably sound odd to you so let me explain.

I have multiple classes that are connecting to multiple rest/web services to grab data from them. For this example lets say that all of those rest are weather forecast services. Each do same thing. Return forecast for some area, but all of them are doing it on theirs own way. For each service I have class that implement gathering data from it and map to my object :

```
public class AForecast
{
    public AForecastResult GetForecast (AForecastRequest request)
    {
         // Grab Forecast
    }
}

public class BForecast
{
    public BForecastResult GetForecast (BForecastRequest request)
    {
         // Grab Forecast
    }
}
```

I'm calling those classes, grab forecast data and then map it into my own object that I work with and this is fine. My problem is that right now I have 13 forecast services. Many of them are using similar method to map forecast result into my own object. Next problem is also that right now probably only I know how can I add new forecast into system. I want to unify that to be able add some interface into Forecast service implementation, and also some base forecast mapper.

I created Interface, but since i Have no idea how forecast result and request will look like it is very generic :

```
public interface IForecast<out TResult, in TRequest>
{
    TResult GetForecast(TReqiest request)
}
```

For each forecast I created separate interface that will implement `IForecast`

```
public interface IAForecast : IForecast<AForecastResult, AForecastRequest>
{
}
```

And my `AForecast` implementation started look like this :

```
public class AForecast : IAForecast 
{
    public AForecastResult GetForecast (AForecastRequest request)
    {
         // Grab Forecast
    }
}
```

Thanks to that I have Forecast services that have it own interface that have common base interface.

Problem is when I want to use it in base class which will be able to call each forecast service and map objects :

```
public abstract ForecastBase
{
    private readonly ?ForecastService _service;
    protected ForecastBase(?ForecastService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public MapedObject GetForecast(DateTime date, string zip)
    {
        var request = GetRequest(date,zip);
        var forecastServiceResponse = _service.GetForecast(request); 
        return Map(forecastServiceResponse);
    } 

    protected abstract MapedObject Map(?Response response);
    protected abstract ?Request GetRequest(DateTime date, string zip);
}
```

Oh this was long. Now final question how can I implement `ForeCast` base class ? Base on my architecture how can I know what type will be `?ForecastService`, `?Request` and `?Response`. I wish i can make mapper like that :

```
public class AMap : ForecastBase
```

And know that in that case `?ForecastService` will be `IAForecast`,  `?Request` will be`AForecastRequest` and `?Response` will be `AForecastResponse` ?

In case you need more explanation feel free to ask.

Comment: Can you post your `ForecastResult` and `ForecastRequest` classes/interfaces?

Comment: I cannot, It depend on Forecast service. It can be string that contain XML, it can be string that contain JSON, but it can also be class form `wsdl` file. It depend on service. Few of them are returning `XElement`

Comment: And I cannot because I don't know that not because I don't want to say.

Comment: What I meant was, can you show the interface and class definitions for requests/results?  Alternately you can copy it to pastebin if you think it will be too large here.

Comment: In that case `AForecastRequest` is an string that contain only zone ( zip code ) and as for `AForecastResult` i got list of strings that have temperature and humidity. for `BForecastRequest` i need to create thier `.wsdl` object and fill it with `zone` , `date` and `key` for authentication and for `BForecastResult` i got `.wsdl` object that contain list of forecast with `temperature`, `forecast` , `opionion` and `tip`. They are not related to each other. And those object don't have own interfaces, and I don't wrapped it in own interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need is the keyword `where` (not only but it's going to play a very important role here).

I defined the interfaces for the request and response like this:

```
public interface IForecastRequest
{

}

public interface IForecastResult
{

}
```

Then we can go on to defining the interface for the Forecast itself:

```
public interface IForecast<out TForecastResult, in TForecastRequest> 
    where TForecastResult : IForecastResult where TForecastRequest : IForecastRequest
{
    TForecastResult GetForecast(TForecastRequest request);
}
```

What happens here is the following. Additionally to your solution, we restrain the generic types to implement our interfaces for request and response. We can then add the generic method to get the ForecastResult. By the way `GetForecast` also doesn't seem like a great name. Better would be `GetResult` or `GetForecastResult` otherwise you'd expect a different return-type.

Now we can implement the BaseForecast. I hope I understood correctly what this is supposed to do. Because you called it ForecastBase, I wasn't sure if this was supposed to do the same thing as IForecast. Maybe a better name would be a good idea here. I implemented it like this:

```
public abstract class BaseForecast<TForecastResult, TForecastRequest> 
    where TForecastResult : IForecastResult where TForecastRequest : IForecastRequest
{
    private readonly IForecast<TForecastResult, TForecastRequest> _service;
    protected BaseForecast(IForecast<TForecastResult, TForecastRequest> service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public MappedObject GetForecast(DateTime date, string zip)
    {
        TForecastRequest request = GetRequest(date, zip);
        TForecastResult forecastServiceResponse = _service.GetForecast(request);
        return Map(forecastServiceResponse);
    }

    protected abstract MappedObject Map(TForecastResult response);
    protected abstract TForecastRequest GetRequest(DateTime date, string zip);
}
```

Here we also have to add the `where`s since we'll have to call the generic methods of the IForecast interface with the same constraints. You can see that in the constructor we provide an instance of an implementation of IForecast which will be our service. This service uses the two generic types we also have in the definiton of this baseclass. The GetForecast-method can now use the generic method of IForecast and the own generic method (GetRequest) to do get the MappedObject (which I don't know what it is). The types all align and you get handy intelisense and compiletime-typechecking for IForecastRequest and IForecastResult.

Please let me know if I understand the purpose of the ForecastBase correctly or not.
I hope this helps. I'm happy to try and answer any questions you might have on this.

Edit:

> I wish i can make mapper like that..

The way you show there doesn't use any generic-type parameters. As far as I understand your intent, you will not be able to do this without specifying what result and request you want to use.
My way of creating an implementation for this is the following:

```
// implement request
public class SomeForecastRequest : IForecastRequest
{

}

// implement result
public class SomeForecastResult : IForecastResult
{

}

// implement forecast itself
public class SomeForecast : IForecast<SomeForecastResult, SomeForecastRequest>
{
    public SomeForecastResult GetForecast(SomeForecastRequest request)
    {
        // return the result you got from wherever
    }
}

public class SomeMapper : BaseForecast<SomeForecastResult, SomeForecastRequest>
{
    public SomeMapper(IForecast<SomeForecastResult, SomeForecastRequest> service) : base(service)
    {

    }

    protected override SomeForecastRequest GetRequest(DateTime date, string zip)
    {
        // return a request from wherever
    }

    protected override MappedObject Map(SomeForecastResult response)
    {
        // map the response and return it
    }
}
```

Edit 2:
I just read your comment which reads the following:

> .. They are not related to each other. And those object don't have own interfaces, and I don't wrapped it in own interface

If you want to keep it this way, there is no way you can create a base-class for you mapper. The mapper need to know that the `AForecast` has a method called `GetForecast`. If it doesn't how is it going to call it. You're going to be in compiler-error land if you try this. You need to tell the compiler "this class can handle any class **if it has the `GetForecast`-method**" otherwise it will refuse to try and call `GetForecast`. The way to tell this to the compiler is by saying "dude look I got this awesome interface which has the `GetForecast`-method. I'm only going to allow the caller to use a class which implements this very interface so you can be sure the `GetForecast`-method exists. Alright?". This is why you use the `where` keyword and I thank you for your question because this is a very good (but not too easy) example on how to use it.

Edit 3:
By the way there is nothing stopping you from using classes instead of interfaces for `IForecastRequest` and `IForecastResult` (of course you would change the name but everything else could stay the same). I don't know what your request and response object is supposed to do/store so I don't know if using classes over interfaces is the right call for you here.
I just wanted to throw out there that this would be possible too.

I'd love to hear some feedback from you :)

Comment: I think that this approach will be best option. Even if `AForecastRequest` will be simple `string` I will wrap it with class `AForecastRequestWrapper`that will implement `IForecastRequest` and add simple `string` field into it. Thanks to this I will be able to use your construction into my structure.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)